# Tcl file exists fails for filenames with chinese characters

Tags: tcl

1. While running a tcl script which checks for file existence,the tcl in-built command (`file exists`) fails because the filepath and filename (`文档名称`) contains chinese characters. I am aware that Unicode characters are supported in Tcl interpreter. I tried command `encoding convertfrom` and `encoding convertto` but it doesn't resolve the issue.
2. Also, when I assign Chinese characters to a string in Tcl, say

   ```
   set a "文档名称"
   puts $a
   ```

   The console prints some weird values ,but not the string with chinese characters. I tried converting the string a to utf-8 using the same encoding command mentioned above, but it didn't work out. I am not sure where I am going wrong in both the cases. Even I tried printing the characters to a file, which also showed some weird characters. Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: What does `encoding system` return for you? What are the “weird characters” you see when you run that code? What platform are you running on?

Comment: My _suspicion_ is that the system encoding (which is actually the encoding used for communicating strings in system calls and the default encoding for all channels) is not matching your operating system; that one thing would have all the strange effects you describe.

Comment: The above command returns the characters æ–‡æ¡£åç§° and the encoding system is cp1252.I am running it on windows 10.

Comment: if encoding system is the issue,Which encoding system should I use for chinese characters?utf-8 or other?If I want to read the japanese characters,should I change the encoding again?

Comment: Well, [`cp1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) doesn't have Chinese characters at all in it. That's the problem. (If you're on non-Windows, the most likely fix is `encoding system utf-8`. On Windows… no idea!)

Comment: What version of Tcl/Tk are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Using the script:

```
set flist [glob *]
foreach f $flist {
  if { [file exists $f] } {
     puts "$f: OK"
  } else {
     puts "$f: NG"
  }
}
set a "文档名称"
set f $a
if { [file exists $f] } {
   puts "$f: OK"
} else {
   puts "$f: NG"
}
```

Just running `tclsh.exe script.tcl`, the last if statement will fail.
The script is read in using the system encoding, and the chinese characters
are not converted correctly.  The first loop using the `glob` statement works.

Using `tclsh.exe -encoding utf-8 script.tcl`, and the final if statement works.

Essentially, the lesson is do not embed utf-8 characters within your script.
Instead, read the data in from a file (using `fconfigure $fh encoding utf-8`),
or from another source and then use the data.

The cmd.exe windows console does not support alternate character sets and cannot
be used for debugging.  It simply will not work.  Instead write the debugging
output to a file and use notepad to view the file.

Comment: IIRC, Tcl's access to the Windows console is via calls that take wide characters anyway.